# Hide play and stop buttons in plotly express animation

Tags: python, animation, plotly, plotly-python

How can I remove the play and stop buttons and just keep the slider?

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=[0, 1, 0, 1],
                       y=[0, 1, 1, 0],
                       z=[0, 0, 1, 1]))
px.line(df, "x", "y", animation_frame="z")
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
fig = px.line(df, "x", "y", animation_frame="z")
fig["layout"].pop("updatemenus")
fig.show()
```

[image]