# Add pause/play button to plotly animation?

Tags: r, animation, plotly

I have a plotly object animated with a rotation, and I would like to add a pause/play button to the object. Currently, the object is automatically rotating when I open it, but I would like to have a pause/play feature. Is anyone sure of how to do this?

```
fig <- plot_ly(joined_most_recent, x = ~diff_hours_since_prev_review, y = ~`Average of time`, z = ~reps, color = ~lapses, colors=c("#5BBCD6", "red"),
             hoverinfo = 'text', 
        text = ~paste0("Swahili: ", Swahili, "<br>", "Translation: ", English, "<br>", "Hours since previously studied: ", round(diff_hours_since_prev_review,1), "<br>", "Average Time Studied (s): ", round(`Average of time`,1), "<br>", "Number of Times Studied: ", reps))


fig <- fig %>% add_markers()
fig <- fig %>% layout(scene = list(xaxis = list(title = 'Hours Since Last Studied'),
                     camera = list(eye = list(x=1.8, y=1.8, z = 0.1)),
                     yaxis = list(title = 'Average Time Studied (s)'),
                     zaxis = list(title = 'Number of Views')),
                      title = "Flashcards by Number of Views and Time Studied", 
                     margin = list(t = -5))%>%
  onRender("
      function(el, x){
  var id = el.getAttribute('id');
  var gd = document.getElementById(id);
  Plotly.update(id).then(attach);
  function attach() {
    var cnt = 0;
    
    function run() {
      rotate('scene', Math.PI / 100);
      requestAnimationFrame(run);
    } 
    run();
    
    function rotate(id, angle) {
      var eye0 = gd.layout[id].camera.eye
      var rtz = xyz2rtz(eye0);
      rtz.t += angle;
      
      var eye1 = rtz2xyz(rtz);
      Plotly.relayout(gd, id + '.camera.eye', eye1)
    }
    
    function xyz2rtz(xyz) {
      return {
        r: Math.sqrt(xyz.x * xyz.x + xyz.y * xyz.y),
        t: Math.atan2(xyz.y, xyz.x),
        z: xyz.z
      };
    }
    
    function rtz2xyz(rtz) {
      return {
        x: rtz.r * Math.cos(rtz.t),
        y: rtz.r * Math.sin(rtz.t),
        z: rtz.z
      };
    }
  };
}
    ")


fig
```

Comment: It's possible, but not as easy as adding an argument or two; see this: https://github.com/plotly/plotly.R/issues/1207

Comment: I think python has it better: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68624485/hide-play-and-stop-buttons-in-plotly-express-animation